# keeping in console output a variable called from another module

Tags: python, function, pycharm, global-variables

I need, running the code in console, to keep in console (store their values in console) certain variables. When I do this in a single file the only thing I need is to declare that variable as a global.

Since I need more modules to been called, **I would like to been memorized in console all the variables declared like globals in others modules**

In the following toy example I have two files: *module.py* where there's the variable I would like to keep in console when the code will end to run; and I have *main.py*.

- If you run in console main.py you will see that the only variable that will be in console after the run ended is `a0` and not `mod1.a1`.

My question is: How can I keep `a1` (the one imported variable from the module), *without using return as function output*, in console output?

module.py:

```
import numpy as np

def rand_variable_frommod1():
    global a1
    a1 = int(np.random.uniform(0,10))
    # print("a1:",a1)
```

main.py:

```
import pathofmodulepy.module as mod1
import numpy as np

def rand_variable_0():
    global a0
    a0 = int(np.random.uniform(0,10))
    # print("a:",a)


for i in range(0,10):
    rand_variable_0()
    print("a0:",a0)

    #calling mod1
    mod1.rand_variable_frommod1()
    print("mod1.a:", mod1.a1)

print("")
print("for ended...!")
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "variable that will be in console".  That phrase does not make sense to me.  Are you using Jupyter?  It's true that globals are all local to the file where they are declared.  You could say, for example, `a1 = mod1.a1` to import the reference into `main`. However, if you later change `a1`  in the module, that won't be seen in the `main` version, because integers aren't mutable.  You could make `a1` a list or object and modify it in place.

Comment: I use pycharm but always use "run in console" mode(ctrl+alt+E), because I can run chunk of code insted the whole script. Yes I thought a sol like yours, but I thought that there would be anything else more automatic. Because in my complete code i will have different variables to use and not just one or two...

Comment: This is strictly a PyCharm issue.  These long-running console sessions that PyCharm and Jupyter use are not typical script environments.  It enables people to use Python the same way that Matlab is used, but production Python scripts are run on the command line and then exit, and their environment evaporates.  It requires different thinking.

Comment: Well this is exactly the environment I'm coming from infact, and R (mostly). Working with big amount of data requires flexibility and I'm finding this in "running in console" mode. The need of a workspace is vital

Comment: Fine.  As long as you have `mod1` imported, you can say `mod1.a1` in your console.  The variables are all present.